# JavaScript - How would i add var into an array with prompts and get the average with a button

Tags: javascript, arrays, prompt

This is my code. I know that it is wrong but I need some help to start a prompt list. My goal is to get 4 marks with a button then you input and have it in an array. It then gets averaged and that gets shown with an alert.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Average your marks
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Start</button>
    <script type="text/javascrypt">
      var student = []

      var student[0] = prompt("Name:");
      var student[1] = prompt("mark=");
      var student[2] = prompt("mark=");
      var student[3] = prompt("mark=");
      var student[4] = prompt("mark=");
      var student[5] = student[1] + student[2] + student[3] + student[4] / 4;

      function myFunction() {
        if (confirm(student) == true)
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at your development console (F12 in most browsers). There are still errors in the code that the console should point straight at for you. Also you shouldn't put ``var`` in front of any but the first reference to student. You only use ``var`` to define a variable. In the other usages, the variable is already defined and you are simply using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually think you are almost there:

change every `avArray` to `student`. and the first time to `var student = []`

edit:
also write `function` instead of `fuction`

edit 2 
finally: because you use `var` you define a variable. so only use `var` with `var student = []`

`var student[0]` is wrong because student is already defined. so use `student[0] =`

Because `prompt` always returns a string you want to use `Number` to make it a number that you can calculate with.

So your final code would look something like this:

```js
var name = prompt("Name:");
var grades = [];
grades[0] = Number(prompt("mark="));
grades[1] = Number(prompt("mark="));
grades[2] = Number(prompt("mark="));
grades[3] = Number(prompt("mark="));
var average = (grades[0] + grades[1] + grades[2] + grades[3]) / 4;

function myFunction() {
  confirm(name + ": " + average)
}
```

```html
Average your marks: 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Start</button>
```

Comment: @MichaelWong also write `function` instead of `fuction`

Comment: what would i do if i wanted the button to start the whole thing and have it automatically pop up the avg after you insert all of the information

Comment: @MichaelWong put it in myFunction before confirm

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that you are adding `int` values, not `String` values - which are the return result of `prompt`.

Try this:

```
// Forces the user to input an int by retrying until an int is input
function intPrompt(msg) {
    while (true) {
        var num = parseInt(prompt(msg));
        if (!isNaN(num)) return num;
    }
}
```

Now here's the code that will read 4 marks from the user and average them:

```
alert((intPrompt('mark 1') + intPrompt('mark 2') + intPrompt('mark 3') + intPrompt('mark 4')) / 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few errors, here are some I've spotted so far:

```
<script type="text/javascrypt">
```

Spell javascript correctly

```
var student[0] = prompt("Name:");
```

You use var only when defining the student the first time, remove it from the next appearances of student.

```
  if (confirm(student) == true)
```

Student is an array, not a string. You will need to convert it to a string in some way to use it for confirm AFAIK.

```
 var student[5] = student[1] + student[2] + student[3] + student[4] / 4;
```

I just tested this line out, and averaging doesn't work correctly, you need to prevent concatenation, maybe proper brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Calculation of average is not the perfect one and you try to put everything into array, even if it does not belong there.
Check the example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWxMEP

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Quiz</title>
<body>
 Average your marks<button onclick=myFunction()>Start</button>
<script type="text/javascrypt">
let name;
let studentMarks = [];
const numOfMarks = 4;
let sumMark = 0;
let msg;
let myFunction = function() {  
    name = prompt("Name");
    if (name.length !== 0){
        for(i = 0; i < numOfMarks; i++){
            msg = "Enter mark (" + parseInt(parseInt(numOfMarks)-parseInt(i) )+" left)";
            studentMarks[i] = prompt(msg);
            sumMark += parseFloat(studentMarks[i]);
        }
        alert(name + "'s average mark is "+ sumMark/numOfMarks);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```